Slack chain on roofing electric tile lift
I'm running a electric roofing tile lift .noticed the chain tensioner is damaged so slack chain would this reduce power under loadas slows down mor weight is put on it

Have you got an engineering design question? You haven't asked any question at all. Welcome to E.SE.

repair the tensioner, otherwise it may slip under load.
